# Facebook sdk friends returning my id instead of theirs

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the newest facebook sdk. I'm using the following code to get friends who are using my app :

```
  private void getUserFriendsFacebookIds() {

        GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/me/friends",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                   public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                   /* handle the result */
                   Log.d("-@-", "graph response " + response.getJSONObject());

                   try
                   {
                   JSONObject data=response.getJSONObject();
                 JSONArray  users = data.getJSONArray("data");

                 if(users!=null)
                 {                 
                 for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++)
                 {

                     JSONObject object = users.getJSONObject(i);

                       String name=object.getString("name");
                       String id=object.getString("id");
                       names.add(name);
                       fbid.add(id);

                     //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        //      name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                 }


                 FacebookLazyImageLoadAdapter adapter=new FacebookLazyImageLoadAdapter(Friends.this,names,fbid);

                friends.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                 }
                   }
                   catch(Exception ex)
                   {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                               "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
    if (response.getError() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "User data error: " + response.getError(), response.getError().getException());
        } else {
            //setUserFriends(response.getRawResponse());
        }
            }
          }
        );

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }
```

The problem is, in the logcat, it's returning my facebook id not their, despite that the response is returning their name, but all the ids are the same (my id). Any help ?

Comment: Can you try isolating the problem? I.e. is this an issue with the Facebook Android SDK, or is this an issue with the Graph API?
You can try making a simple Graph API request for `/v2.4/me/friends` first, and see what kind of data you get back. If that response contains also just your own app-scoped ID for all returned friend objects, you should file a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs. If not, should add some example output from your logcat to the question so others can use that information to decide where to look next.